# Laravel authentication between different back-end project

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I have two or more back-end API(Laravel) projects and a single front-end React JS project. From the front-end app, I will call all of the back-end API projects.

When the user login, authentication will check in `App 1`(with Laravel passport) and return `access_token`.

I want to use these `access_token` when calling API from both `App 1` and `App 2`. But, the main problem is how to check `access_token` validation from `App 2` to `App 1` server.

To solve this problem, I think but not sure it is the correct way or not, I can create middleware in the `App 2` server and get every incoming `access_token` and send it to check validation to `App 1`. If return true, user can access, else can't access.

But, I think this way is inappropriate because every incoming request needs to check `access_token` validation from `App 2` to `App 1`, it will slow down the server and bottleneck problem.

I already search a lot of posts on google but, not yet find the best way for me. I found one way OAuth server implementation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7RfBgoeg48 but, I think that way is not working well in my project structures because I have a lot of customization.

I'm also read the discussion on reddit(https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/dqve4z/same_login_across_multiple_laravel_instances/) but, I still didn't understand very well.

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

1. I expect you have a database containing all your access and refresh tokens for your users - so just create a database access from the App2 backend server to the database containing your access and refresh tokens and just check them directly in the App2 via the new database connection.
2. Create the middleware that will check user authentication from App2 to App1, but as you correctly pointed out, that would cause an extra loading time.
3. Depending on whether you need the end user to know that he's connecting to "another server" - meaning App2 - you can use Oauth2 authorization - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUG6BHgJR9w

Option 1. seems like the best solution to me

[image]

Comment: For the Option 1, I'm not clearly understand how can I check App2 backend server to the App1 database(that include access and refresh token) ?

Comment: @Cloud you don't need to check the database via the communication from App1 => App2, you can just directly access the database from App2.

Here's your current flow as you are thinking about it: App2 asks App1 for authorization, App1 accesses the database with access and refresh tokens, App1 returns authorization response to App2, App2 proceeds with the rest of the code after succesfull auth.

What I'm proposing is this: connect App2 directly to the database App1 is using, that way you can directly query the database for the access tokens without having to ask App1.

Comment: Now, I try to check token validation as you guide me. In App2, I create a middleware, in that middleware I connect to database that user tokens exists. And get token from incoming request of App2 and then try to check that token is valid or not. The main problem is, I don't know how to validate `acess_token` because when issuing `access_token` from App1, I use laravel passport. Passport is automatically save "token id" in `oauth_access_tokens` table, not token itself. I'm stuck in here to validate token.

Comment: 1. install laravel pasport in App2
2. use the same method of access token validation in App2 as you use in App1